# Is it possible to remove or modify readonly variable?

Tags: bash, readonly

I set a variable as `readonly` in bash but can't remove the variable using `unset`. How to remove the readonly variable?

```
[root@test ~]# readonly xyz=2

[root@test ~]# echo $xyz
2

[root@test ~]# xyz=44
-bash: xyz: readonly variable

[root@test ~]# unset xyz
-bash: unset: xyz: cannot unset: readonly variable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a feature of read-only variables in `bash`.  A read-only variable cannot be changed or unset:

From the `bash` manual, regarding `declare -r` (the same as `readonly`):

> `-r`
>   Make names readonly.  These names cannot then be assigned
>           values by subsequent assignment statements **or unset**.

Comment: Which is somehow obvious, because otherwise you could `unset` is and then set it no another value, which is against the `readonly` concept.